# can we reduce the size of image when adding to database

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does the size of image affects the speed of retrieving data form database.
If so is there any solution? so that we can reduce the size of image while saving image to the database.

I think, when there is too large data say 100000 records records then it obviously affect the speed. What do think?

Thanks,
Rupali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of image does not affect the speed of retrieving data form database. If size of image is more then it will take more time to transfer image from server to web page.

What you can do is while saving the image, just reduce the size of image using some image processing tools.

```
    **Example:**
     http://www.imagemagick.org/
```